# Maven command : add classpath directory for Java runtime

Tags: maven, classpath

I'am running a Maven command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

or

```
mvn test
```

I have a custom directory on my post containing libraries to load at runtime.
How do I specify it in a Maven command ?

Thanks.

Comment: @dubes This is not a duplicate, IMHO. The question there is about the Maven _build_ classpath (in its `default` lifecycle) which is something completely different than running a Spring Boot application. This is also the reason for `spring-boot:run` having its own _folders_ parameter to extend  its classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`spring-boot:run`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html):

> **folders**   Additional folders besides the classes directory that should be added to the classpath.